# Add sidebar(left) to custom layout in Magento

Tags: list, magento, layout, view, php

I have a custom module layout that I made for my Magneto site.  The issue is that the layout is 1 column with no sidebar on the outside()left or right).  However I need to find a way to add the sidebar into the product grid to the left.  It can't exist outside the col-main div.  Would something like this be done within the custom layout PHTML file or the list PHTML file?  I'm relatively new to Magneto so any insight would be appreciated.

This is the custom layout PHTML file

```
 <div class="col1-layout">
            <div class="main">
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('breadcrumbs') ?>
                <div class="col-main specialLayout1Col">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="infoContainer">
                                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_messages') ?>
                                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('content') ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> <div class="col1-layout">
            <div class="main">
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('breadcrumbs') ?>
                <div class="col-main specialLayout1Col">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="infoContainer">
                                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_messages') ?>
                                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('content') ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

This is the list.PHTML file product grid

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-12">
    <ul class="products-grid products-grid--max-<?php echo $_columnCount; ?>-col">
        <?php $i=0; foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
        <?php /*if ($i++%$_columnCount==0): ?>
        <?php endif*/ ?>
        <li class="item<?php if(($i-1)%$_columnCount==0): ?> first<?php elseif($i%$_columnCount==0): ?> last<?php endif; ?>">
            <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" class="product-image">
                <?php $_imgSize = 210; ?>
                <img id="product-collection-image-<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>"
                src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize($_imgSize); ?>"
                alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" />
            </a>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <div class="productGridDivider"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="product-info">
                <h2 class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true) ?>"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?></a></h2>
                <?php
                // Provides extra blocks on which to hang some features for products in the list
                // Features providing UI elements targeting this block will display directly below the product name
                if ($this->getChild('name.after')) {
                $_nameAfterChildren = $this->getChild('name.after')->getSortedChildren();
                foreach ($_nameAfterChildren as $_nameAfterChildName) {
                $_nameAfterChild = $this->getChild('name.after')->getChild($_nameAfterChildName);
                $_nameAfterChild->setProduct($_product);
                echo $_nameAfterChild->toHtml();
                }
                }
                ?>
                <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>
                <?php if($_product->getRatingSummary()): ?>
                <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, 'short') ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <div class="actions">
                    <?php if(!$_product->canConfigure() && $_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                    <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button>
                    <?php elseif($_product->getStockItem() && $_product->getStockItem()->getIsInStock()): ?>
                    <a title="<?php echo $this->__('View Details') ?>" class="button" href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>"><?php echo $this->__('View Details') ?></a>
                    <?php else: ?>
                    <p class="availability out-of-stock"><span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <ul class="add-to-links">
                        <?php if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow()) : ?>
                        <li><a href="<?php echo $this->helper('wishlist')->getAddUrl($_product) ?>" class="link-wishlist"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?></a></li>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php if($_compareUrl=$this->getAddToCompareUrl($_product)): ?>
                        <li><span class="separator">|</span> <a href="<?php echo $_compareUrl ?>" class="link-compare"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Compare') ?></a></li>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <?php /*if ($i%$_columnCount==0 || $i==$_collectionSize): ?>
        <?php endif*/ ?>
        <?php endforeach ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use css to do that

```html
 <div class="col1-layout">
            <div class="main">
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('breadcrumbs') ?>
                <div class="col-main specialLayout1Col">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="infoContainer"> <!-- give column size 12 -->
                                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_messages') ?>
                              <div class="left"> <!-- give column size 3 -->
                                
                                <?php echo "call you left content block here" ?>
                                </div>
                              <div class="col-main"> <!-- give column size 9 -->
                                
                                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('content') ?>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

but carefull while setting up css

Comment: I understand I can use css, however that is not the correct method.  What I found I had to do was to remove the catalog.leftnav from the catalog.xml and then place it within the 'content' inside my local.xml.